# angular - how to know when a promise completes using EventEmitter

Tags: angular

I am using EventEmitter and need to know when a promise completes so I can perform other actions.

//child.component.ts

```
...
class ChildComponent{
    @Output onDoSomething() = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(){}

    public async doThis(){
        await this.onDoSomething.emit(); <---- how do I know when this completes?
        doSomeOtherThings();
    }
}
```

//child.component.html

```
...
<div (click)="doThis()"></div>
```

//parent.component.html

```
<child-component (onDoSomething)="doSomething()"></child-component>
```

//parent.component.ts

```
...
class ParentComponent{

    constructor(){}

    public doSomething(){
         return Promise.all([
             Promise1, 
             Promise2, 
             Promise3
         ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your child component has nothing to with waiting for parent. It just emits command to parent to get some data, then you should provide it down to child with @Input. `<child-component [data]="dataFromParent" (onDoSomething)="doSomething()"></child-component>`

Comment: not sure this solves the problem. I still want to doSomething after the emit()

Comment: would `await this.doSomething().take(1).toPromise()` work?

Answer (score 0):

my understanding of your goal here is that the parent component will react to the completion of a task from child component.

If this is the case then the child component's method could be changed to below:

```
public async doThis(){
    await doSomeOtherThings();
    this.onDoSomething.emit();
}
```

the statement 'this.onDoSomething.emit();' will notify the parent control that the task has been completed.

The parent component will then call upon the event handler: doSomething().

Answer (score 0):

I Believe you are trying to do two way communication between child and parent components. I prefer to use a service for this.

If my understanding is correct your use case is like this:

1. Child Component: doThis() is clicked --> Notify Parent Component (this.onDoSomething.emit())
2. Parent Component listens to the child event and executes doSomething(), that returns a promise/notification/data?
3. Child component needs to consume returned promise/data and execute some other functions

I would basically create a service shared by both parent and child. Let’s call it DoSomethingService.ts

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DoSomethingService { 
      public doSomething: BehaviorSubject<YourData> = new BehaviorSubject<YourData>(null);
     //note YourData is your custom data that you want to pass to child component

}
```

On your parentComponent:

```
class ParentComponent{

    constructor(private service: DoSomethingService){}

    public doSomething(){
         let yourData = Promise.all([
             Promise1, 
             Promise2, 
             Promise3
         ]); // Or anything that you want to pass to child component

    this.service.doSomething.next(yourData);

    }
}
```

Your child component:

```
class ChildComponent{
    @Output onDoSomething() = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private service: DoSomethingService){
      this.service.doSomething.subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
         //This will fire after the parent has executed DoSomething()
        //do something with this data from parent
      }
    })

    }

    public async doThis(){
        this.onDoSomething.emit(); 
        doSomeOtherThings();
    }
}
```

If you want, you can further extend this service for all communication, removing the need to use @output.

Hope this helps.